# Support ActionBar won't display the right color with API 21

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to make an appcompat theme but the color isn't working, and the icon won't show either... maybe im missing something. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <color name="background_test">#410000</color>
    <color name="font_general">#ffffff</color>
    <style name="MyTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    </style>

    <!-- general styles for the action bar -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="background">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_test</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

What should i add to make it work?

EDIT:

It won't work with a toolbar either... After i set:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

It will lose all the user defined theme and will only get the parent theme... Here are my xmls (Yes i have a lot of redundant/test values as i wanted to try everything)

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyActionBarStyle"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/MyActionBarStyle"
        />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <color name="background_test">#410000</color>
    <color name="font_general">#ffffff</color>
    <!-- general styles for the action bar -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:panelColorBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/background_test</item>

        <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/background_test</item>

        <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->


        <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarStyle">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/background_test</item>

        <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
        <item name="android:panelColorBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/background_test</item>

        <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/background_test</item>

        <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background_test</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_test</item>

        <item name="background">@color/background_test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

Screenshot:

```
http://i.imgur.com/4iohVwP.png
```

New EDIT:
It won't work from the code either...

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar test=getSupportActionBar();

    test.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //this is the only one working...
    test.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x410000));

    test.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    test.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

EDIT:

There are some bugs reported for the new Appcompat-v7, this is probably a bug:

```
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Toolbar` then your `actionBarStyle` is **not** used.

You need to style Toolbar directly:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="..."
    android:background="..."
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="..."
    app:subtitleTextAppearance="..." />
```

There are more attributes you can customize, these are just examples.

I'm not sure why `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(...)` doesn't work for you, I've just tried it in various places and it works fine.

Comment: the setBackgroundDrawable is now working. But, do i really need to setup every toolbar instead using styles? Somehow the toolbar isn't getting any attr from the style and i even tried to use the described parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"

Comment: main theme is parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", does the main theme as NoActionBar and the Toolbar theme with an actionbar parent may cause a conflict? how do i declare a style for all my toolbars then if they are acting as actionbars?

Answer (score 1):

It is an example:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

</style>
```

Also I suggest you using the new [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).

You can find more info here:

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: Will never work with default actionbar, color still the same but the Toolbar suggestion is the best so i won't waste my time with regular ActionBar

Comment: It won't work either... When i setup the toolbar as supportactionbar will lose it's color!. I edited the question.

Comment: If i set "background" on the theme it will change the color, but, it will also force everything else with the same color so even the transparent images will look bad

Comment: Probably a bug... Appcompat-v7 has some bugs reported

Answer (score 0):

One solution to get the **AppCompatActivity** to use the **primary theme color** on the **Action Bar** for all api levels is to declare the colors in the same theme like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

      <!--API < 21 -->
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

      <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorButtonNormal</item>

      <!-- 21 < API this is probably not needed, included for illustration -->
      <item name="android:colorPrimary" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/colorAccent</item>

      <item name="android:colorButtonNormal" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/colorButtonNormal</item>

 </style>
```

> **note:** remember to remove the theme declared in values-v21 for this to work